# Check for illegal character combinations with jQuery.Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Trying to check an input on an html form to ensure that it does not contain &# together in the string. I am using jQuery.Validate http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation and have all the regex's I need to check the other inputs but need to ensure that one field in particular does not have the & and # together. The trick is that these characters are allowed in the field, just not together. So the user can put iAm&some#Test  but could not put iAm&#someTest.

This is the method for checking the field:

```
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("allowed", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9a-z\-.,:?!@$*&#]+$/i.test(value);
     }, "");
```

Assume that it would be something like this for the check:

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod("dissallow", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[&#]+$/i.test(value);
 }, "");
```

But this only checks to make sure that & and # are allowed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether two consecutive characters are part of the disallowed group as given below

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("dissallow", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || !(/[&#][&#]/i.test(value));
}, "Some rule");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ntfqX/)